# Why does VideoJS's $("#video")[0].player.pause() break in IE8?

Tags: jquery, html, video, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to control the play and pause function an HTML5 video using the [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) plugin and the following command:

```
  $("#clip")[0].player.pause();
```

Everything works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE8.

The debugger says:

> this.player is null or not an object.

This command also works in the other browsers but not in IE8:

```
   $("#clip")[0].pause();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `$()[0]` makes no sense. Since some time `$()` creates an empty jQuery object....

Comment: of course there's an element in there but I left it out. Looks something like this: $("#clip")[0].player.pause();

Comment: they say to use it like this on the website: http://videojs.com/jquery/

Comment: @kareldc: That significantly changes the meaning of your question, since `$()` is valid, and used to actually be used in jQuery code. You should edit this to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 doesn't support html5 video tag

Comment: Sorry, looks like `video-js` should provide fallback on a flash player. Are you sure you initialize videojs method first?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a class, instead of an ID?

Maybe IE8 doesn't like the multiple ID's on the same page?

```
 $(".clip")[0].player.pause();
```